# Writing each element of a list to each file

Tags: python

I want write the content of a list to files.The list contain the content of each photos requested from to the google api place photos. When I try to write the content of the list to the files all the file ends up with the same photo

This the code I tried for writing to the files
anyone can help

```
from flask import render_template
import urllib.parse
import requests
import geocoder
import json
import imghdr
import io
import os

@app.route("/NearbyShops")
def NearbyShops():


    final_url = nearby_search_url + urllib.parse.urlencode({'location':'34.015353,-6.830001',
                                                            'radius':'1500',
                                                            'type':'restaurant',
                                                            'key':''})
    places_req = requests.get(final_url)
    places_req.text
    results = json.loads(places_req.text)
    list_photo_reference = []
    list_name = []
    new_list_name= []
    list_requests = []
    lent_list_rq=len(list_requests)
    lent = len(results)


    for i in range(lent):
        for ph in results["results"][i]["photos"]:
            list_photo_reference.append(ph["photo_reference"])

    for n in results["results"]:
       list_name.append(n["name"])

    for ref in list_photo_reference:
        photo_final_url = photos_url + urllib.parse.urlencode({'maxwidth' :'350', 
                                                               'photoreference' :ref,
                                                               'key':''})
        photos_req = requests.get(photo_final_url)
        list_requests.append(photos_req.content)


    for rq,name in zip(list_requests,list_name):
            photo_name= name.replace(" ","_") + "." + imghdr.what("", rq)

            photo_dir = "App/static/photos/" + photo_name

            with open(photo_dir, "wb+") as f:
                f.write(rq)
                f.close()


    image_name = os.listdir('App/static/photos')

    return render_template('NearbyShops.html', title='Nearby Shops',image_name=image_name)
```

Comment: Wait a second, isn't `fi` in `for fi in f:` a `bytes` object? You shouldn't be able to call `write` and `close` on that. Is that the actual code you're running?

Comment: yes this is the code an runing in flask

Comment: You don't need to do `                    f.close()`. The `open()` context manager does that when exited.

Comment: Also, can you show include an [mcve]? Where is `imghdr` defined, what does a sample `list_requests` look like, what does a sample `list_name` look like?

Comment: I have shown the whole code

Answer (score 0):

Your code says:

> For each request (or whatever `rq` is), write said request into *every single file* from `list_name`.

So, the computer does exactly this, and you end up with *the same request/photo* written to all of these files.

You probably wanted to iterate over `(photo, file)` pairs:

```
for rq, name in zip(list_requests, list_name):
    photo_name = ...
    ...
```

This requires that `list_requests` and `list_name` be of equal lengths.

Comment: thank you for your respond, I used zip and it did write the content of the list_requests to the folder but one photo overwrite like 3 names in the list_name which is the list of places.its because they don have the same size. but am retrieving the photo and the name of the paces they should have the same size.

Comment: If they should be of the same size but actually aren't, there's a problem somewhere where you generate these lists

Comment: I was using a for loop to display the photos name of the place using jinja in the page,I took off the for loop and it writes only 4 files even if I change the radius or the types in the paramaters of the request to the google api places